# Row background color in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

In asp.net application, I am using grid-view control in that I am binding the data to the `label` which is in `grid-view`.
If **data is empty** then the **color of the row** should be in red 
If not I mean if data is there to bind  then the **row in green**.
This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Holiday Region">
     <ItemTemplate >
         <asp:Label ID ="lblholdareg" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Holidaregion") %>' >
         </asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on `rowdatabound` function of `gridview` as follows

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         //change it according your cell number or find element
         if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "")
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Green;
         else
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;   
    }
}
```

Comment: I cancelled out your downvote, not sure why you were DV'd.  Your solution isn't complete but it is headed int he right direction.  The other answers all set color of a label which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: hi @Șhȇkhaṝ but the event is not firing...,

Comment: @Anjali you need to add the event on `gridview` `OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"` [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the RowDataBound event, get into the e.Row item, and assign either a CSS class or directly set the background color.  I prefer setting a CSS class so you can change the rendering of it without a recompile later.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Holiday Region">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblholdareg" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Holidaregion") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the code-behind, I had to assume you were using a DataTable as your data source, update the code to fit your data structure:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataRow row = (System.Data.DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;
    if (row["Holidaregion"] == null || row["Holidaregion"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "row-empty";
    }
    else 
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "row-full";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Holiday Region">
  <ItemTemplate >
    <asp:Label ID ="lblholdareg" runat ="server"
     CSSClass='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmply(Eval("Holidaregion")))?"red:green" %>' 
     Text ='<%# Eval("Holidaregion") %>' >  
    </asp:Label>

   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Edit:**

Instead of fighting with grid view inline and code behind stuffs, just use a jQuery and achieve the same in client side

Comment: k i will try and let u know murali

Comment: where are you setting the `row-color`?

Comment: @Shekhar, I hope you know about using CSS. Here I added into Label, samething can be applied in row also. Control the style using CSS classes

Comment: how can you set the row color using your code I think not possible. You need to go for `row data bound`.

Comment: @Shekhar, Let me go back to year of 2005 and use GridView sample now and let you know. I started using ListView, which is very flexible. Now only MVC not web forms :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Control l = e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
  ((Label)l).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: he want to set `row color`

Comment: Right, but in that row he has a label so he wants to set the label background colour and not the row colour...

Comment: I don't see in the question about label background.

Answer (score 0):

try it this code it is every row in color change with the category wise or filters wise
 http://devloper4u.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-set-color-in-every-row-on.html