# gridview label color change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
 protected void getmessagelisting()
    {    
          ds = new DataSet();
            SQL = "Select * from [magaj].[message] where UId='" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "'  order by ID desc";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, _connect());
            da.Fill(ds, "message");
            Grid_Joblist.DataSource = ds;
            Grid_Joblist.Columns[0].Visible = true;
            Grid_Joblist.DataBind();
            Grid_Joblist.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["isread"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    //  (e.Row.FindControl("lblsubject") as Label).ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid_Joblist.Rows)
                    {
                        Label lblsubject = row.FindControl("lblsubject") as Label;
                        lblsubject.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;

                    }
                }
            }
}
```

now when i run this then i will bind all the data in proper way 
but when i want to do like if any data having `value of isread=0` then i want to change the color of that label.

but when any 1 row  is  satisfy with this if condition then it will change the all other label color also..

i want to only change the label color if it is satisfy with `isread=0` and for other data which is not satisfy with this then it will be the different color

how can i do this?

Comment: when the Grid is being redrawn why not do your color logic there..?

Comment: where i can write ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do one thing :

just print your isread value in label like :

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblisread" Text='<%#Eval("isread")%>' Visible="false"/>
```

then change your function as below:

```
   foreach (GridViewRow row in Grid_Joblist.Rows)
    {
        Label lblsubject = row.FindControl("lblsubject") as Label;
        Label lblisread = row.FindControl("lblisread ") as Label;

        if (lblisread..Text == "0")
        {
            lblsubject.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        }
        else
        {
            lblsubject.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }

    }
```

and its done... !!
Cheers..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use GridView RowDataBound event to use set label color.

something like below

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Display the company name in italics.
      System.Data.DataRow row = (System.Data.DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;
      if(row["isread"].ToString()=="0")
        {

           Control l = e.Row.FindControl("lblsubject");
  ((Label)l).ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

    }

  }
```

Not tested code.

Check these links for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[Row background color in gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082232/row-background-color-in-gridview)